# battleships python code academy

Tags: python

For some reason the if statement I have for checking if the guessed location and actual location are the same just isn't working. I've set it up so I know where the ship is. I've tried getting it to print out all the variables and their respective types just after I've input the guess and just before it checks they're equal but for some reason it just goes on and says I've missed.

but anyway here it is:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

print ship_row
print ship_col

##########################################
#Value error checking and guess row inputs
##########################################
def get_guess_row():
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    return guess_row
def value_guess_row():
    try:
        y = get_guess_row()
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a valid number.")
        y = value_guess_row()
    return y

##########################################
#Value error checking and guess col inputs
##########################################
def  get_guess_col():
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
    return guess_col
def value_guess_col():
    try:
        x = get_guess_col()
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a valid number.")
        x = value_guess_col()
    return x        

###############################
#Get the coloumn and row values
###############################
guess_col = value_guess_col()
guess_row = value_guess_row()

guess_col -= 1
guess_row -= 1


print ("Guessed coloumn: ", guess_col, "the type is: ", (type(guess_col)))
print ("Guessed row: ", guess_row, "the type is: ", (type(guess_row)))
print ("Actual coloumn: ",  ship_row, "the type is: ", (type(ship_row)))
print ("Actual row: ", ship_col, "the type is: ", (type(ship_col)))

# Write your code below!
if  guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print  ("Congratulations! You sank my battleship!")

elif guess_row not in range(5) or \
     guess_col not in range(5):
        print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":
    print  ("You guessed that one already.")

else:
    print ("You missed my battleship!")
    board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    print_board(board)
```

Comment: You mean that at some point it writes for example "Guessed row: 3" and "Actual row: 3" and same thing for columns,  but still answers that you missed?

Comment: exactly,  although apparently it works in actual python rather than code academy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and it appears to work fine:

```
O O O O O    
O O O O O
O O O O O    
O O O O O
O O O O O
4
1
Guess Col:2
Guess Row:5
('Guessed coloumn: ', 1, 'the type is: ', <type 'int'>)
('Guessed row: ', 4, 'the type is: ', <type 'int'>)
('Actual coloumn: ', 4, 'the type is: ', <type 'int'>)
('Actual row: ', 1, 'the type is: ', <type 'int'>)
Congratulations! You sank my battleship!
```

A few things to keep in mind that might be confusing you:

1) When you print the random column and row, you show it exactly as the list index looks:
    4
    1

But when you ask for the values, you subtract 1 from the read value (hence if the random row is `3`, you input should be `4`)

2) When you print the values that the system generated, you have misplaced rows and columns, change it to:

```
print ("Actual coloumn: ",  ship_col, "the type is: ", (type(ship_row)))
print ("Actual row: ", ship_row, "the type is: ", (type(ship_col)))
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. When I print out the actual locations at the top I thought they were printing out the other way around so ended up putting in the co-ordinates in the wrong way around, this along with printing the wrong way around the second time around made them look right.

Comment: @NoahHourigan glad to hear that, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: omg I went onto the next section and it just got rid of all the stuff I had added, such as  accepting strings.  I'm so annoyed, I spent like hours adding that stuff.